# How to add a space in front of every two characters/symbols in R

Tags: r, gsub

My vector

`a <- c( '4152.0', '34152', '235518.3', '1235518.335554', '15235518.3876')`

How to add a space in front of every two symbols, but only before a dot?

`'41 52.0', '3 41 52', '23 55 18.3', '1 23 55 18.335554', '15 23 55 18.3876'`

Comment: Close-voters: *"needs details or clarity"*? I think it's rather clear: we have sample data and expected output. The only thing we don't have is evidence of effort, which is not strictly a close-vote reason. *"needs focus"*? This asks one very specific question, there's no ambiguity. If you're going to close-vote, that's your right/privilege, but at least make it a relevant reason.

Comment: Needs focus or clarity is incorrect here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prettyNum` has arguments `big.interval` and `big.mark` which supports this.

```r
prettyNum(a, big.interval = 2, big.mark = " ")
# [1] "          41 52.0" "          3 41 52" "       23 55 18.3"
# [4] "1 23 55 18.335554" " 15 23 55 18.3876"
```

If you need the leading blank space removed, use `trimws`.

Comment: @akrun, I wonder if it's in response to my "harsh" comment, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Thanks for the support.